# Consul set up without docker for production use

Tags: microservices, consul

I am doing a POC on Consul for supporting service discovery and multiple microservice versions. Consul clients and server cluster(3 servers) are set up on Linux VMs. I followed the documentation at [Consul](https://www.consul.io/intro/index.html) and the set up is successful.

Here is my doubt. My set up is completely on VMs. I've added a service definition using HTTP API. The same service is running on two nodes. 
The services are correctly registered:

```
curl http://localhost:8600/v1/catalog/service/my-service
```

gives me the two node details.

When I do a DNS query:

```
dig @127.0.0.1 -p 8600 my-service.service.consul
```

I am able to see the expected results with the node which hosts the service. But I cannot ping the service since the service name is not resolved.

```
ping -c4 my-service or ping -c4 my-service.service.consul
```

ping: unknown host.

If I enter a mapping for `my-service` in /etc/hosts file, I can ping this, only from the same VM. I won't be able to ping this from another VM on the same LAN or WAN.
The default port for DNS is 53. Consul DNS interface listens to 8600. I cannot use Docker for DNS forwarding. Is it possible I missed something here? Can consul DNS query work without Docker/dnsmasq or iptables updates?
To be clear, here is what I would like to have as the end result:

```
ping my-service
```

This needs to ping the nodes I have configured, in a round robin fashion.

Please bear with me if this question is basic, and I've gone through each of the consul related questions in SO.

Also gone through [this](https://blog.nimbusscale.com/2015/12/28/leveraging-consuls-dns-interface/%20%22%22) and [this](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/02/06/quick-intro-to-consul/%20%22%22) and these too says I need to do extra set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait!  Please don't do this!

DO. NOT. RUN. `CONSUL`. AS. ROOT.

Please.  You can, but don't.  Instead do the following:

1. Run a caching or forwarding DNS server on your VMs.  I'm bias toward `dnsmasq` because of its simplicity and stability in the common case.
2. Configure `dnsmasq` to forward the TLD `.consul` to the `consul` agent listening on `127.0.0.1:8600` (the default).
3. Update your `/etc/resolv.conf` file to point to `127.0.0.1` as your nameserver.

There are a few ways of doing this, and the official docs have a write up that is worth looking into:

https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/forwarding.html

That should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Sean. Instead of running consul as a root, I've reduced privilege of the DNS port.

Comment: You'll find other benefits of running a caching DNS server on port 53 re: application performance and stability in the event of network interrupts or consul disruptions, but thank you for using `setcap` (which isn't portable, but works).

Comment: Hi Sean, I've decided to go with dnsmasq. No hassle and less number of steps.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a pretty complicated topic, but the simplest way is to change consul to bind to port 53 using the ports directive, and add some recursers to the consul config can pass real DNS requests on to a host that has full DNS functionality. Something like these bits:

{
  "recursors": [
    "8.8.8.8",
    "8.8.4.4"
  ],
  "ports": {
    "dns": 53
  }
}

Then modify your system to use the consul server for dns with a nameserver entry in /etc/resolve.conf. Depending on your OS, you might be able to use a port in the resolv.conf file, and avoid having to deal with Consul needing root to bind to port 53.

In a more complicated scenario, I know many people that use unbound or bind to do split DNS and essentially do the opposite, routing the .consul domain to the consul cluster on a non-privileged port at the org level of their DNS infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Jay. I've been just trying to avoid doing anything as the root user. Would you have any ideas on that?

Comment: I get this error, because I cannot login as root user: `Error starting dns server: dns udp setup failed: listen udp 127.0.0.1:53: bind: permission denied`

Comment: If you have no access to root, or something like sudo, you're probably out of luck for shimming something in at the system level. In order to have something passively work for everything on the host, you'll need *something* binding on port 53. That doesn't have to be consul, it could be something like bind or unbound, but more than likely, you'll still need root to set those up as well.

Comment: Thanks again. Here is how I did it. I added the recursors of the DNS servers to the agent config, and did bind port 53 with consul: `sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip </path/to/consul binary>` I added the local DNS resolver in the resolv.conf file. With these changes, I was able to successfully do a `dig` and `ping`.

Comment: You can setcap with ansible https://github.com/brianshumate/ansible-consul/pull/292/files#diff-0b5c8ae5d27614dd347875e6a31f9dfc